# PowerShell ISE runas user reports other user with whoami

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domain, user, runas

I want to start a PowerShell ISE session as a domain user. If I enter:
`runas.exe /netonly  /user:domain.local\username "powershell ise"`

I am prompted for the password and the ISE environment launches. However, running `whoami` gives the following output:
`win-machine\user`

This is the local machine and user I am logged in as.

Being familiar with some Linux and `sudo` usage, my intention is to perform the equivalent user change and make Active Directory queries with `domain.local\username` privileges through the shell. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Note that I cannot join the domain from the host.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that you don't need to join the domain in order to use `runas`, whether with or without `/netonly`. That is, assuming the domain allows NTLM auth — if it enforces Kerberos auth you're out of luck. I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because it is explicitly what you requested.

I would recommend reading up on what the `/netonly` switch does: http://www.pseale.com/pretend-youre-on-the-domain-with-runas-netonly

---

### Why this happens

Basically a *normal* `runas` will run the program under the specified user, much like `sudo -u` would do in Linux. This means all local and remote actions occur under the specified user.

However, when you pass the `/netonly` switch, things get weird. `runas` ends up running the program locally under the *currently logged in* user, **but** any network requests (presumably, anything that does Kerberos/NTLM/SPNEGO auth) use the specified user.

`whoami` only checks the *local* user. Since you specified `/netonly`, this is unchanged, and you'll have all the permissions of your currently logged in user, you'll use your current user's profile for any settings, etc.. All up until you make a request to a networked computer, at which point you'll impersonate the user you specified in the `runas` command.

If this is what you want, great! If not, and if you actually want the program to run fully under the specified user even on the local machine, remove the `/netonly` switch from your command.

---

### Verifying the user

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a simple command like `whoami` to check which user you're running as remotely when using `/netonly`.

If you have some form of command remoting enabled, you could possibly use those. Without them, the simplest method I can think of is connecting to a network share and checking which share you are connected to from the other end.

#### From computer1:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\TestUser2 powershell
```

And inside the powershell instance:

```
net use \\computer2
```

Which will connect to the `IPC$` share of `computer2` using the remote/`netonly` user. You can later undo this with `net use /delete \\computer2`.

#### From computer2:

```
net share IPC$
```

This should give you a list of connected users, which should include the one you `runas`'d:

```
Share name        IPC$
Path
Remark            Remote IPC
Maximum users     No limit
Users             TestUser2
Caching           Manual caching of documents
Permission        Everyone, FULL

The command completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you're running is correct, I utilize this almost every day.

Once in PowerShell ISE with that command, you should be able to Enter-PSSession or cd \computername\share

I generally change the Window Title of the screen I'm in to help me remember which /netonly domain and account I specified
`$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "remotedomain-otheraccount"`